# Java - inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, data-hiding

```
class Base
{
        int x=1;
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
class Child extends Base
{
    int x=2;
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Child c=new Child();
        c.show();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT is 1.
The method show is inherited in Base class but priority should be given to local variable and hence the output should have been 2 or is it that the compiler implicitly prefixes super before it??

Comment: Polymorphism does not apply to fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not overriding the `show` method in `Child`, the `Base`'s version will be used. Therefore it cannot see the `x` variable you defined in `Child`. Your IDE (if you are using one) should give you a warning that you are "hiding a field".

You can achieve the expected functionality by setting the `x` of a `Child` object after instantiating it. Try:

```
class Base
{
    int x = 1;

    void show() {        
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class Child extends Base
{
    public static void main(String s[]) {

        Child c = new Child();

        c.show();
        c.x = 2;
        c.show();
    }     
}
```

This should yield 1 and then 2.

EDIT: Note this works only when the `x` field is accessible from the `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's because the Child didn't override the show() method.  The only one available is the one from Base, which displays its version of x.

Try it this way - it'll display 2:

```
class Base
{
        int x=1;
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
class Child extends Base
{
    int x=2;
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Child c=new Child();
        c.show();
    }
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**With one Show Method**

```
class Child extends Base
{
    public Child(int x)
    {
        super(x); // Assumes a constructor in the parent that accepts an int.
        // or
        super.x = x;
    }
}
```

Then you will only need the one `show()` method.

**With Two Show Methods**

You override the functionality of the superclass, in it's child classes, as follows:

```
class Child extends Base
{
    public void show()  
    {
       // OVerrides the code in the superclass.
       System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

*Which should you prefer?*

You're trying to override functionality, so you should favour the second option.

Answer (score 0):

`Base` class doesn't know about `Child` class, so the `show()` method will never call the variable from it's subclass.

So, if you want to show the `x` from the subclass override the `show()` method by reimplementing it in the `Child` class.